# determine which button clicked inside of a service

Tags: android

have a simple service running, and I have some buttons each that do a different thing (I want them too). Im not sure how to let the service know which button was pressed. When I press a button I want a service to start regardless but depending on which button pressed It needs to do something different.

**SERVICE CLASS**

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    private int i = 1;

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } 

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        i++;
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        // Do task depend on cliked view
        String clickedView = intent.getStringExtra("clicked_on");
        if ("BUTTON1".equals(clickedView)) {
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Egg")
            .setContentText("One Added!");
        } else if ("BUTTON2".equals(clickedView)) {
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Egg")
            .setContentText("Two Added!");
        }else if ("BUTTON3".equals(clickedView)) {
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Egg")
            .setContentText("One Subtracted!");
        }else{
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Egg")
            .setContentText("Woo Lets Eat!!");
        }

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent( 0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(i, mBuilder.build());

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

// Start the  service
public void startNewService(View view) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    if (view.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        serviceIntent.putExtra("clicked_on", "BUTTON1");
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        serviceIntent.putExtra("clicked_on", "BUTTON2");
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.button3) {
        serviceIntent.putExtra("clicked_on", "BUTTON3");
    } else {
        serviceIntent.putExtra("clicked_on", "BUTTON4");
    }
    startService(serviceIntent);
}

// Stop the  service
public void stopNewService(View view) {     
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**MAIN XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:textColor="@color/LightSalmon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:text="@string/add_one" 
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:onClick="startNewService"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_two" 
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sub_one" 
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/make"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cnt"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:textColor="@color/LightSalmon"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? It seems to me you just want to send some data to a `Service` when it's started. That's basically just using an Android `Service` as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You should use `AsynTask` instead of `Service`.***

But here is the solution for your current approach (But I would go for AsyncTask)

Modify startNewService which will read the id of button clicked and send to Service into intent extra.

```
public void startNewService(View view) {

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    // Read id of view and put extra.
    if (view.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        serviceIntent.putExtra("clicked_on", "BUTTON1");
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        serviceIntent.putExtra("clicked_on", "BUTTON2");
    }
    startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

Now override `onStartCommand` of Service which having intent as param. You can read extra and do task depend on that.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
    // Do task depend on cliked view
    String clickedView = intent.getStringExtra("clicked_on");
    if ("BUTTON1".equals(clickedView)) {
        // Do task for button 1
    } else if ("BUTTON2".equals(clickedView)) {
        // Do task for button 2
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but if you dont mind one more question. The service works for determining if the first of 4 buttons was pressed but does not react to the other three? if you have time could you help me resolve this (im still trying to learn) i will update the OP

Comment: Handle `serviceIntent.putExtra("clicked_on", "BUTTON2");` properly for each buttons. That will work for all.

Comment: No need to write `serviceIntent.putExtra("clicked_on", "BUTTON2");` into else block of `startNewService()` just comment/ remove that line. Your code will work perfect then.

Comment: yeah that was a typo I meant for it to be serviceIntent.putExtra("clicked_on", "BUTTON4"); and no the code doesnt work at all, still only for the first button

Comment: Did you clear the notification?? If one notification is showing just clear that before pressing other button.. And put log into each if, and tell me which is not working.

Comment: even if i press the Button2 first, and never press the 1st button it still doesnt realize i pressed the 2nd one

Comment: How did you cal this method on button click?? show the code

Comment: the xml for each button `android:onClick="startNewService"`

Comment: Did you set id for each buttons?

Comment: Yes, button1, button2, button3, button4. Thanks for trying to help me troubleshoot this issue by the way

Comment: Ok. Then put log inside startNewService() and print id of view to make sure that if this method has been called on button click.

Comment: not sure I follow sorry. Im still new so I'm probably not much help of you trying to help me

Comment: :) A little mistake :). You didn't added `android:onClick="startNewService"` for all buttons. Check and add.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following:

1. Start the service once the app started
2. Make the service listen to 2 broadcast action
3. On some button click send broadcast to the service with it specific action

Comment: the service has to begin and end with each button click. So like I click one it does its thing and then the service ends. So idk if that would work?

Comment: It will work any way, but consider using async task instead of service , if the whole process need to continue even if the app is not in foreground so use service.